# How to view a pdf when click on a page?

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I have a pdf in my media. I'd like to open this pdf in an other panel in my browser when i click on the page.

Example:

I have a menu with:

Page1  Page2  Page3

I click on the Page1 and in an other panel the pdf is displayed.

Comment: another panel means in new browse tab?

Comment: Yes, in a new browser tab.

Comment: ok how you are calling PDF? using any plugin or simple href?

Comment: I'm not using any plugin at this moment. I just uploaded the file on my media in wordpress.

Comment: ok and that you want to open on click on menu? or Page1 is just link?

Comment: i want that page1 is directly a link to the pdf, and this is open in a new tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96662/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-legolas07).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that you want the menu item Page 1 to be a PDF link? If so, log into your admin panel and do the following:

1. Go to your Media Library and left click once on your PDF. You should be able to grab the link to the PDF from the info that appears on the right hand side of the screen.
2. Go to **Appearance > Menus**. In the upper right hand corner of the browser window is a tab labeled **Screen Options**.

When you click the **Screen Options** tab, a panel slides out. There is a section called **Advanced Menu Properites**. In that section, click the checkbox next to **Link Target** and close the Screen Option tab.

3. Add your menu item as a Custom Link. Once added to your menu, there will be an option for you to specify to open the link in a new window/tab.
4. Save your menu and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your **page 1** is as link text in page , Below code will open that PDF in new browser tab:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/20/PDFNAME.pdf" target="_blank">Page 1</a></p>
```

`target="_blank"` helps to open link/page/pdf in new tab.